# How to resize a collection of usercontrols placed in a container using MVVM (developing vertical scale)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I use MVVM. My goal is to develope a kind of vertical metric scale control (SkipScaleView).
My idea is to full ListBox (or Stackpanel) completly with a control (ScaleMeter) in such a way that there should not be any scrollbar or whitespace. So I've got:

part of SkipScaleView XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Meters}">
        <ListBox.DataContext>
            <local:SkipScaleViewModel/>
        </ListBox.DataContext>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <local:ScaleMeter />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

SkipScaleView CodeBehinde is empty.

part of SkipScaleViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<IScaleElement> Meters { get; set; }

for (int i = 0; i < meterCount; i++)
{
   ScaleMeterModel meterModel = new ScaleMeterModel();
   Meters.Add(meterModel);
}
```

ScaleMeter XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="....ScaleMeter"
             Padding="0,1,0,0"
             MinHeight = "10"
             MinWidth="10"
             Background="Blue"
             Padding="0,1,0,0"
             >
<Grid/>
</UserControl>
```

My question is: how to ajust ScaleMeter height using MVVM?
Perhaps my strategy is wrong and there is a more elegent way to do it.

Note. I know how ajust ScaleMeter height without MVVM.

**Upd**
meterCount = 450

Comment: Use an items control instead of listbox. Make the items panel a uniform grid.

Comment: @Andy Yes, but it will not work for me. Sorry I didn't say in my ScaleMeter I use TextBlock as well and a lot of ScaleMeters (200 or more) so height of them wiil de small and then TextBlock (I set visible only TextBlocks ending with "0") will not be visible.

Comment: Maybe create `Height` property in ScaleMeterModel and  bind your ScaleMetter user control's Height property to it: